# Excel VBA Copy Worksheets into new Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to select a number of worksheets, open a new workbook and pastes the worksheets into the new workbook.

I've come across a few solutions online but they all seem to be very long and require you to input an address for the new workbook. I don't want to do this as I want the end user to be able to save the file wherever he or she wants to.

The below code allowed me to create a new worksheet but only with the activated worksheet

```
Sub CopyToNew2()
'Copy the active sheet to a new Workbook.
    ActiveSheet.Copy
End Sub
```

So I tried changing it to the code below but it didn't work because it seems that I you can only activate one workbook at any one time

```
Sub Macro44()

Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).Activate
ActiveSheet.Copy

End Sub
```

Finally, I found this code that does exactly what I want, except it attempts to save the file.

```
Sub Macro43()
'

Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")).Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
     .SaveAs Filename:=Environ("TEMP") & "\New1.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

End With

End Sub
```

Is there any way I can change the first code so that the sheets I have predetermined copy and open in a new worksheet?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Eliminate the `With...End With` block from your `Macro43` sub, i.e. just the first line of that will do what you appear to want.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I don't know why I wasn't able to find a simple explanation like yours online. Thanks!!!